# Filter List of Locations from the closest to the most distant

Tags: android, firebase, geofire

My App uses the **Firebase Database** to display a list of Event.
From the moment the App starts, **I get the User current Location** and it's updated if it changes.
What I would like to do is to **display the List of Event** based on the User current Location, going **from the closest event to the most distant**.

I have implemented **Geofire** in my App and get all the events withing the given Radius but unfortunately they are not filtered based on the closest to the most distant.

As far as I know, Geofire doesn't support this filtering yet (but do not hesitate to correct me if I'm wrong).

However, in my Adapter, I get a **List of Model** that I could filter on the fly, each Models have a coordinates property with value.
So does anyone know **how to filter based on Coordinates String or Locations objects?**

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

**1) Add the distance property (double field) to your Event object**;

**2) Calculate distance from user**:

```
double distance = GeoUtils.distance(userLoc.getLatitude(), userLoc.getLongitude(), eventLatitude, eventLongitude);
event.setDistanceInMeters(distance);
```

**3) After you finish the Geofire call order your collection of events**:

```
Collections.sort(eventsList, new Comparator<Event>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Eventt1, Eventt2) {
                return Double.valueOf(t1.getDistanceInMeters()).compareTo(t2.getDistanceInMeters());
            }
        });
```

**4) ....**;

**5) PROFIT**;